# Isomorphism between integers and symmetry group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a little slow on this this.

Consider the subgroup $<\sigma>$ where $\sigma = (1 3 746)$ of $S_7$. Why is $<\sigma>$ isomorphic to $<\mathbb{Z_5},+>$?

I know that two elements of $\sigma$ are fixed, which explains the '5' case, but doesn' explain how they are isomorphic to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the successive powers of $\sigma$:

$$\begin{align*}
\sigma&=(13746)\\
\sigma^2&=(17634)\\
\sigma^3&=(14367)\\
\sigma^4&=(16473)\\
\sigma^5&=\text{identity permutation}
\end{align*}$$

In other words, $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $5$. All cyclic groups of order $5$ are isomorphic, so it’s isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb Z_5,+\rangle$. One isomorphism is given by $\sigma^k\mapsto k$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

With a little more experience you’ll realize that you don’t need to do the actual calculations: an $m$-cycle in a permutation group always has order $m$. Thus, if $\sigma$ is an $m$-cycle, $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is always isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb Z_m,+\rangle$, and one possible isomorphism is the map $\sigma^k\mapsto k$ for $0\le k<m$. There are others. **Exercise:** If $a$ is relatively prime to $m$, then the map $\sigma^k\mapsto ak\bmod m$ is an isomorphism of $\langle\sigma\rangle$ to $\langle\Bbb Z_m,+\rangle$.

Comment: Oh does the "+" come from multiplying the sigmas? Like $\sigma^4 \sigma = \sigma^{4+1} = \sigma^{5} = \sigma^{0}$?

Comment: @sizz: Not really: the $+$ is simply the group operation in $\langle\Bbb Z_5,+\rangle$. It would be better to say that the law of exponents $\alpha^m\alpha^m=\alpha^{m+n}$ is what makes the map in question an isomorphism of groups.

Comment: yeah that's kinda what i was trying to get at. in $S_7$, the operation is composition of functions and in $\mathbb{Z_5}$, it is addition. The mapping that takes place for this isomorphism is $<S_5, \circ> \to <\mathbb{Z_5},+>$

Comment: @sizz: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: What happens if I have a subgroup like $\sigma = (1 3 4)(2 5)$ in $S_7$? The $\sigma$ is disjoint, so it takes $6$ times, $\sigma^6 = e$. The operation wouldn't change. So for instance $\sigma^5 = \sigma^{3+2} = \sigma^3 \sigma^2$ It would be $\mathbb{Z_6}$ for those reasons?

Comment: I also unfortunately have to regret not being to do your added exercise because I have no idea what relatively prime even means... lol

Comment: @sizz: Two integers are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor is $1$, like the numerator and denominator of a fraction in lowest terms. $\langle(134)(25)\rangle$ is indeed isomorphic to $\langle\Bbb Z_6,+\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sigma$ has order $5$. Now if the group $G=\langle g \rangle$  and $g$ has order $n$ then $G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$. 
The function $f:G \to (\mathbb{Z}_n,+) , g^k \mapsto k$ is an isomorphism.